# Interview Question... Trying to work it out, but couldn't get an efficient solution

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I am stuck in one interview question.. The question is,

> *given two arrays A and B. A has integers unsorted. B has the same
>   length as A and its values are in the
>   set {-1,0,1}
>
> you have to return an array C with the
>   following processing on A.
>
> if B[i] has 0 then C[i] must have A[i]
>   if B[i] has -1 then A[i] must be in C
>   within the sub array C[0] - C[i-1] ie.
>   left subarray
>   if B[i] has 1 then A[i]
>   must be in C within the sub array
>   C[i+1] - C[length(A)] ie right
>   subarray.
>
> if no such solution exists then
>   printf("no solution");*

I applied following logics:-

```
int indMinus1 = n-1;
int indPlus1 = 0;

//while(indPlus1 < n && indMinus1 > 0)
while(indPlus1 < indMinus1)
{
    while(b[indMinus1] != -1)   {
        if(b[indMinus1] == 0)
            c[indMinus1] = a[indMinus1];
        indMinus1--;
    }
    while(b[indPlus1] != +1)    {
        if(b[indPlus1] == 0)
            c[indPlus1] = a[indPlus1];
        indPlus1++;
    }

    c[indMinus1] = a[indPlus1];
    c[indPlus1] = a[indMinus1];
    b[indMinus1] = 0;
    b[indPlus1] = 0;
    indMinus1--;
    indPlus1++;
}
```

But this will not going to work,, for some cases like {1,2,3} >> {1,-1,-1}... One output is possible i.e. {2,3,1};

Please help.... does their any algorithm technique available for this problem?

**Correct Solution Code**

```
int arrange(int a[], int b[], int c[], int n)
{

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if(b[i] == 0)
        c[i] = a[i];
}

int ci = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if(b[i] == -1)  {
        while(c[ci] != 0 && ci < i)
            ci ++;
        if(c[ci] != 0 || ci >= i)
            return -1;
        c[ci] = a[i];
        ci++;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if(b[i] == 1)   {
        while(c[ci] != 0 && ci < n)
            ci ++;
        if(c[ci] != 0 || ci <= i)
            return -1;
        c[ci] = a[i];
        ci++;
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if you put all the possible numbers of A in each position of C, then just dfs'd those possibilities?

Comment: i dont get you?? can you please elaborate??

Comment: Create a linked list for each index of C, then loop through A/B.  If B[i] = -1, then insert A[i] into the linked lists C[0..n-1] and similarly for B[i] = 1.

Then what you basically have is a depth-first search problem.   I'm fairly certain that this works, though there might be a simpler solution.

Comment: @kevmo - This insertion might shift the elements that were inserted before, to the place beyond where they existed before insertion. Please correct me if i am wrong?? or i understood the solution differently..

Comment: No, a dfs will produce the correct solution. It doesn't matter if the elements moved, the solution will satisfy all the conditions. It has a slightly better bound than Grigor's solution, but that might not be worth the more complicated implementation.

Comment: @kevmo - we would like to see your implementation using dfs... Please if you can start a separate answer for your thoughts... :)

Comment: Just being nasty ... what if `a` can have zero?

Comment: @AGeek: Grigor's solution appears to be correct and much simpler, so no need for dfs.  Basically the dfs finds all solutions by imposing the bounds, whereas Grigor's produces one solution.  Since the problem only says find one solution, Grigor's works fine.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I suggest the following algorithm: 
 1. Initially consider all `C[ i ]` as empty nests.
 2. For each i where `B[ i ] = 0` we put `C[ i ] = A[ i ]`
 3. Go through array **from left to right**, and for each `i` where `B[ i ]  = -1` put 
`C[ j ] = A[ i ]`, where `0 <= j < i` is the **smallest** index for which `C[ j ]` is still empty. If no such index exists, the answer is impossible.
 4. Go through array **from right to left**, and for each `i` where `B[ i ]  = 1` put 
 `C[ j ] = A[ i ]`, where `i < j < n` is the **greatest** index for which `C[ j ]` is still empty. If no such index exists, the answer is impossible.

Why do we put A[ i ] to the leftmost position in step 2 ? Well, we know that we **must** put it to some position j < i. On the other hand, putting it leftmost will increase our changes to not get stucked in step 3. See this example for illustration:

```
A: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
B: [ 1, 1,-1 ]
```

Initially C is empty: `C:[ _, _, _ ]`
    We have no 0-s, so let's pass to step 2.
    We have to choose whether to place element `A[ 2 ]` to `C[ 0 ]` or to `C[ 1 ]`.
    If we place it **not** leftmost, we will get the following situation:
    `C: [ _, 3, _ ]` 
    And... Oops, we are unable to arrange elements `A[ 0 ]` and `A[ 1 ]` due to insufficient place :( 
**But**, if we put A[ 2 ] leftmost, we will get 
`C: [ 3, _, _ ]`,
And it is pretty possible to finish the algorithm with
`C: [ 3, 1, 2 ]` :)
**Complexity**: 
What we do is pass three times along the array, so the complexity is `O(3n) = O(n)` - linear.


**Further example:**

```
A: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
B: [ 1, -1, -1 ]
```

Let's go through the algorithm step by step:
1. `C: [ _, _, _ ]`
2. Empty, because no 0-s in `B`
3. Putting `A[ 1 ]` and `A[ 2 ]` to leftmost empty positions:

```
C: [ 2, 3, _ ]
```

4. Putting `A[ 0 ]` to the rightmost free (in this example the only one) free position:

```
C: [ 2, 3, 1 ]
```

Which is the answer.

**Source code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


vector< int > a;
vector< int > b;
vector< int > c;
int n;

bool solve ()
{
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < n; ++i )
        c[ i ] = -1;
    for( i = 0; i < n; ++i )
        if( b[ i ] == 0 )
            c[ i ] = a[ i ];
    int leftmost = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < n; ++i )
        if( b[ i ] == -1 )
        {
            for( ; leftmost < i && c[ leftmost ] != -1; ++leftmost ); // finding the leftmost free cell
            if( leftmost >= i )
                return false; // not found
            c[ leftmost++ ] = a[ i ];
        }
    int rightmost = n - 1;
    for( i = n - 1; i >= 0; --i )
        if( b[ i ] == 1 )
        {
            for( ; rightmost > i && c[ rightmost ] != -1; --rightmost ); // finding the rightmost free cell
            if( rightmost <= i )
                return false; // not found;
            c[ rightmost-- ] = a[ i ];
        }
    return true;
}


int main ()
{
    cin >> n;
    a.resize(n);
    b.resize(n);
    c.resize(n);
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < n; ++i )
        cin >> a[ i ];
    for( i = 0; i < n; ++i )
        cin >> b[ i ];
    if( !solve() )
        cout << "Impossible";
    else
        for( i = 0; i < n; ++i )
            cout << c[ i ] << ' ';
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Grigor In step 4, I think you meant to say "where `B[ i ] = 1`," not `-1`.

Comment: Thanks for the sol... Can i please know the running time of this algorithm ??  Also, does it work for this input array "a is {1,2,3}, b is {1, -1,-1},"...The probable output could be "c should be {2,3,1}"

Comment: @AGeek Should be linear, about O(3n).

Comment: No.. it seems O(n^2) logic.. the example that i gave in my last comment,, the solution will fail for that input instance.. Please correct me on my understanding..

Comment: It's linear, I will edit now and add show the result for your example

Comment: @AGeek No, after step 3 you get {2,3,_} and after step 4 you got {2,3,1}. And it's linear as each step just walks over the array one time (not for each element), as you can keep track of the smallest/greatest free index during traversal.

Comment: How abt this input set....... int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
 int b[]={1,1,0,-1,1,1,-1,-1};
 int c[]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; >>>>>> It should work for this as well....  Then the solution seems fine....

Comment: @ Grigor - No. the soln seems not correct.. or can you please write up the code to provide more clarity on your soln?

Comment: @AGeek: Let's see this case. First we will get c={0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0}. Then, putting characters to the left, we get c={4,7,3,8,0,0,0,0}. And finally putting the rest to the right, we get c={4,7,3,8,1,2,5,6}, which is the correct answer.

Comment: @Grigor..thanks for demonstrating this example.. but i don't know there is some intutive feeling.. that this will break for some input instance.. or are you feeling sure abt the solution, that it will work for every case?

Comment: @Grigor: I'm pretty sure this is O(n^2).  Each -1/1, you have to make a sweep of max length n.  So n sweeps of max length n => O(n^2).

Comment: @kevmo314: Well, if you once found a leftmost position, the next one will be on the right of it, sure ? So, we do not need to sweep on length n every time, just we move rightwards our existing pointer to the leftmost position, which means we make 2*n moves, not n^2 , which is linear. You can see it in my source code, added to the answer.

Comment: Guys, this is obviously linear! What's all the commotion about N^2?

Comment: @AGeek: well, thinking for almost an hour already I couldn't find any input data on which this approach will give wrong result. Actually, it's some kind obvious that putting elements leftmost when -1 is met is the best - we leave as much rightmost free space as possible, which will give us best chances when putting elements to right :)

Comment: Ya Grigor, i understood it completely now why you putting it in leftmost for -1, and rightmost for +1 logic.. Thanks a lot.. :)

Comment: @Grigor: You need to sweep to the leftmost position.  Big O notation is about theoretical worst case, not about how it actually works.  The absolute worst case scenario here is that you have to sweep n positions.

@Armen: It's not "obviously linear".

Comment: @kevmo314: Are you serious? This is O(N) PERIOD. If you don't understand it, look closer

Comment: @kevmo314: Bring a "worst case" for which the algorithm is doing number of operations proportional to N^2 and I'll agree you're right. But since you can't do that because it's impossible, then I guess I won't agree with you :)

Comment: @kevmo314: I didn't mean to offend you, but the mathematical fact remains that this is a linear algorithm. I can't give you a mathematical proof of that in a comment. You can convince yourself by counting (programmatically) the number of operations and seeing different results for different N's. You'll see a linear connection

Answer (score 2):

Far too much time spent: ;-)

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
static int doit(int A[], int B[], int C[], size_t size)
{
    size_t first_free = size - 1;
    size_t last_free = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (B[i]) {
            if (i < first_free) {
                first_free = i;
            }
            if (i >= last_free) {
                last_free = i;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (B[i] < 0) {
            if (first_free >= i) {
                return 0;
            }
            C[first_free] = A[i];
            first_free = i;
        } else if (B[i] == 0) {
            C[i] = A[i];
        }
    }
    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (B[i] > 0) {
            if (last_free <= i) {
                return 0;
            }
            C[last_free] = A[i];
            last_free = i;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int b[] = { 1, -1, -1 };
int c[sizeof(a) / sizeof(int)];
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (!doit(a, b, c, sizeof(a) / sizeof(int))) {
        printf("no solution");
    } else {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(int); ++i)
            printf("c[%zu] = %d\n", i, c[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Code without comments looks a complete nightmare to me to crackk!! Anyway i am trying to understand it.. Thanks for posting.. :)

Comment: @AGeek It's actually not much different from Grigor's algorithm, which would be the one I would suggest for accepting.

Comment: @AGeek Fortunately, I'm not being interviewed. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This can be reduced to network flow.  Here is how to construct the gadget:

1. For every element, i, of A, create a node a_i, and add a unit capacity edge from the source to a_i.
2. For every element, i, of C, create a node c_i, and add a unit capacity edge from c_i to the sink.
3. For all 0 values in B with index i, add an edge from a_i to c_i, again with unit capacity.
4. For all -1 values in B with index i, add an edge from a_j to c_i, where 0<= j < i.
5. For all 1 in B with index i, add an edge from a_j to c_i where i < j < n.

Example gadget:

```
   a_0 *----* c_0
      / \    \
     /   \    \
    /     |    \
   /  a_1 | c_1 \
S *----*  | *----* T
   \    \ \/    /
    \    \/\   /
     \   /\ | /
      \ /  \|/
       *    *
      a_2   c_2


  B = [ 0, 1, -1]
```

A maximal flow in this network with capacity = n corresponds to an assignment of a's to c's.  To get the permutation, just compute the min-cut of the network.

Comment: Killing a sparrow with a nuke, are we? ;)

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: There's no kill like overkill :)  Plus this is much easier to code up if you got some network flow code sitting around.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with a single outer pass. As `i` goes from `0` to `n-1`, `j` goes to `n-1` to `0`. The `l` and `r` indexes point to the first available "flex" spot (where `b[i]  != 0`). If at any point `l` passes `r`, then there are no more free flex spots, and the next time `b[i] != 0` the outer loop will break prematurely with a "no solution."

It seemed to be accurate, but if it does fail on some cases, then adding a few more conditions to the loops that advance the flex indexes should be sufficient to fix it.

There is an extraneous assignment that will happen (when `b[i] == 0`, `c` will be set by both `i` and `j`), but it is harmless. (Same goes for the `l > r` check.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define EMPTY 0 

int main()
{
  int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
  int b[] = {1, -1, -1};
  int c[] = {EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY};

  int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);

  int l = 0, r = n - 1;
  int i, j;

  /* Work from both ends at once.
   *   i = 0 .. n-1
   *   j = n-1 .. 0
   *   l = left most free "flex" (c[i] != 0)  slot
   *   r = right most free flex slot
   *
   *   if (l > r) then there are no more free flex spots
   *
   *   when going right with i, check for -1 values
   *   when going left with j, check for 1 values
   *   ... but only after checking for 0 values
   */

  for (i = 0, j = n - 1; i < n; ++i, --j)
  {
    /* checking i from left to right... */
    if (b[i] == 0)
    {
      c[i] = a[i];

      /* advance l to the next free spot */
      while (l <= i && c[l] != EMPTY) ++l;
    }
    else if (b[i] == -1)
    {
      if (i <= l) break;

      c[l] = a[i];

      /* advance l to the next free spot, 
       * skipping over anything already set by c[i] = 0 */
      do ++l; while (l <= i && c[l] != EMPTY);
    }

    /* checking j from right to left... */
    if (b[j] == 0)
    {
      c[j] = a[j];
      while (r >= j && c[r] != EMPTY) --r;
    }
    else if (b[j] == 1)
    {
      if (j >= r) break;

      c[r] = a[j];
      do --r; while (r >= j && c[r] != EMPTY);
    }

    if (l > r)
    {
      /* there cannot be any more free flex spots, so
         advance l,r to the end points. */
      l = n;
      r = -1;
    }
  }

  if (i < n)
    printf("Unsolvable");
  else
  {
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      printf("%d ", c[i]);
  }

  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```